# $E$ is a vector bundle over $X$. If $w_1(E)=0$, then distinct orientations on $E$ are in 1-1 correspondence with $H^0(X,Z_2)$?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $E$ be a vector bundle over $X$. Assume $X$ is connected and "nice" space.

"If $w_1(E)=0$, then distinct orientations on $E$ are in 1-1 correspondence with elements of $H^0(X,Z_2)$." ($w_1(E)$ is first stiefel-whitney class.)

$\textbf{Q:}$ Why orientations of $E$ are in 1-1 correspondence with elements of $H^0(X,Z_2)$ here? Consider $1\to SO(n)\to O(n)\to Z_2\to 1$ with $n=rank(E)$ over real number. This induce long exact sequence $\dots\to H^0(X,Z_2)\to H^1(X,SO(n))\to H^1(X,O(n)\to H^1(X,Z_2)$ where last map is representing $w_1$ map and $E$ is identified as an element in $H^1(X,O(n))$. Now $w_1(E)=0$ implies $E$ can be oriented or $E$'s structural group is reduced to $SO(n)$. It is clear that there are 2 orientations on $E$. However, it is not clear that distinct orientations on $E$ are in 1-1 correspondence with elements of $H^0(X,Z_2)$. I think what the book means is just sending $E^+$(one choice of orientation) and $E^-$(the other choice of orientation) to $Z_2=H^0(X,Z_2)$. This does not mean there is a reverse map going from $H^1(X,SO(n))\to H^0(X,Z_2)$.

Ref. Spin Geometry, Lawson, Chpt 2, Theorem 1.2

Comment: It's saying (intuitively) that you get two orientations on every path component of $X$, and thus a total of $2^n$ orientations where $n$ is the number of path components of $X$.

Comment: @jgon That is clear to me. However, is he implying there is a map "homomorphism" with some structure on $H^1(X,SO(n))$ $H^1(X,SO(n))\to H^0(X,Z_2)$? I do not think $H^1(X,SO(n))$ is a group if $n\geq 2$ as it is not abelian in that case.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if he's trying to say there's a homomorphism of some form, I don't have enough context for that. I can only assume that he means what I wrote in my first comment based on what you've quoted. Additionally, I have no idea what cohomology with coefficients in Lie groups is supposed to mean, and I can't find it anywhere else online, so I can only assume it's nonstandard. You should probably include a definition of it, or if possible, a link to a definition.

Comment: @jgon Take $G$ as a group which maybe lie group and $U_i$ covering $X$. Consider $g_{ij}:U_i\cap U_j\to G$ s.t. $(g_{ij})$ is cocycle and this gives $(g_{ij})\in H^1(\{U_i\},G)$. Take the direct limit over all possible refinements. That is definition of $H^1(X,G)$ where $G$ is any group.